# Problema do URI 1061 - C#

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema que o código abaixo ele me resulta o resultado correto, porém, quando eu envio para o site ele informa o erro **RUNTIME** (vetor ou array com menos capacidade do que o necessário para o problema, ou quando você tenta acessar uma de memória inválida.)
Não consigo visualizar o motivo do erro, alguém poderia me ajudar??

site do exercício para visualização: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1061

```
            Console.Write("Dia ");
        int diaI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // vetor string dados ínicio da festa
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] tempoI = line.Split(':');
        int horaI = int.Parse(tempoI[0]);
        int minI = int.Parse(tempoI[1]);
        int segI = int.Parse(tempoI[2]);

        Console.Write("Dia ");
        int diaF = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // vetor string dados encerramento da festa
        string line2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] tempoF = line2.Split(':');
        int horaF = int.Parse(tempoF[0]);
        int minF = int.Parse(tempoF[1]);
        int segF = int.Parse(tempoF[2]);

        int diaT = 0, horaT = 0, minT = 0, segT = 0;

        //lógica para verificar tempo
        {
            //segundos
            if (segI > segF)
                segT = (60 - segI) + segF;
            else if (segI == segF)
                segT = 0;
            else
                segT = segF - segI;

            //minutos
            if (minI > minF)
                minT = (60 - minI) + minF;
            else if (minI == minF)
                minT = 0;
            else
                minT = minF - minI;

            //hora
            if (horaI > horaF)
            {
                horaT = (24 - horaI) + horaF;
                diaT = (diaF - diaI) - 1;
            }
            else if (horaI == horaF)
            {
                horaT = 0;
                diaT = (diaF - diaI) + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                horaT = horaF - horaI;
                diaT = (diaF - diaI);
            }

        }

        //imprimindo
        Console.WriteLine("{0} dia(s)", diaT);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} hora(s)", horaT);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} minuto(s)", minT);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} segundo(s)", segT);
```

Comment: Pode ser uma questão de Cultura, como o formato de data padrão no servidor estar diferente, como por exemplo MM/dd/YYYY

Comment: Opa leandro, como assim questão de cultura, pq como o site depura o código acho q isso não interferiria ou não??

Comment: Pera, o que você quer dizer com envia para o site, o que você tem é uma aplicação console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O URI nem sempre vai enviar entradas válidas para o seu programa, pelo que me lembro, e por isto, seu código deve esperar por erros e tratá-los.

Exemplo:

`// Caso 1
int horaI = int.Parse(tempoI[0]);
int minI = int.Parse(tempoI[1]);
int segI = int.Parse(tempoI[2]);`


`// Caso 2
int horaF = int.Parse(tempoF[0]);
int minF = int.Parse(tempoF[1]);
int segF = int.Parse(tempoF[2]);`

Caso haja alguma leitura de linha inválida, resultaria numa exception index out of bounds devido a não ter uma array com o tamanho que você está acessando. 
Veja se não é este o problema.

Recomendo o uso do TryParse ao invés de Parse.
Outra recomendação é você dar uma olhada na classe DateTime, não sei se é possível/permitido usá-la mas faz todo o cálculo que você faz na mão facilmente. O pouco que usei o URI fazia usando C.

Comment: Muito obrigado Kevin, mas eu tinha encontrado o problema que erá na primeira linha, que o erro tava na primeira linha devido o Console.Write, ele sempre entra com a informação e não é necessário a impressão por parte do programador, mas agora que conheço o DataTime e o TryParse, seria bem mais fácil, mas muito obrigado!!!

Ps: Como eu finalizo essa Pergunta??

Comment: Você pode responder sua pergunta e marcá-la como resposta, logo ao lado da sua resposta terá um sinal de correto, basta clicar e ele ficará verde. No caso de alguém responder corretamente pra você (num futuro post), basta marcar a desta pessoa como correta. Acredito que seja desta forma